# Angular scope and bindToController use cases

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular lets you specify scope for your directive like so:

```
            var directive = {
                restrict: 'EA',
                scope: {},
                bindToController: {
                    text: '='
                },
                controller: DirectiveController,
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                templateUrl: 'directive.partial.html',
                link: DirectiveLink
            };
```

I understand that bindToControllers sets a namespace within scope.
In this directive template I can data bind text like so:

```
            <span>{{vm.text}}</span>
```

If I did not use bindToController and used scope instead I can data bind text like so:

```
            <span>{{text}}</span>
```

Everybody seems to be suggesting that bindToController is the way to go, but I want to know why.

So my question is when should I use scope and when should I use bindToController?
Are there any use cases when I should just use scope?

Thanks.

Comment: It just continues the morphing of directives into components. For `bindToController` use cases see -- [No $scope soup, bindToController in AngularJS](https://toddmotto.com/no-scope-soup-bind-to-controller-angularjs/).